# Why Can't I Clear Two Sublists Of An ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, arraylist, sublist

In my class, Main, I'm trying to take an xml file, turn it into a string, tokenize it and put it into an Array List, and then clear away the majority of the ArrayList values using a sublist and then clearing that sublist so that I can get rid of the data that I don't need and keep the data that I do need. It all worked fine until I tried to clear away the data that I didn't need. What happened was that the first sublist clear worked, but the second sublist clear didn't. I researched and troubleshooted for hours to find out why this didn't work but I didn't come up with anything. If it helps I'm using Eclipse Kepler Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

```
package mccoy.alfred.project;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/USD/rss.xml");
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            ArrayList<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>();
            int tokenNum = 0;

            while (true) {
                int data = buf.read();

                if (data == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    sb.append((char)data);
                }

            }

            String xmlFile = sb.toString();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(xmlFile);
            System.out.println("tokens count: " + st.countTokens());

            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                String token = st.nextElement().toString();
                tokenList.add("Token " + tokenNum + " = " + token);
                tokenNum++;
            }

            tokenList.set(64, "Token 64 = Dirham");
            tokenList.subList(0, 56).clear();
            tokenList.subList(65, 77).clear();

            System.out.println(tokenList);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I would put what the code outputs to the console, but it is very long. Again, the part of the code that doesn't work is:

```
tokenList.subList(0,56).clear();
tokenList.subList(65,77).clear();
```

Also, if it helps, I plan on adding more sublists and clearing them if someone can fix this. Thanks for putting up with the long post and thank you in advance for helping me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the order:

```
tokenList.subList(0, 56).clear();
tokenList.subList(65, 77).clear();
```

You remove the first 57 elements, elements at indexes 64 through 76 are now in indexes 9 through 21.

If you're only ever going to remove two chunks, just swap the order so that you touch the end of the list first.

```
tokenList.subList(65, 77).clear();
tokenList.subList(0, 56).clear();
```

Comment: I know that it says not to say "thank you", but thank you so much! It's the right answer and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2803078 no problem. I gather you're new to StackOverflow, the common approach to 'rewarding' correct answers is to upvote and/or select the 'best' as answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have not taken account of the fact that removing elements from a list alters the size of the list, and the position of all elements after the removal range.

For instance:

```
        tokenList.set(64, "Token 64 = Dirham");
        tokenList.subList(0, 56).clear();
```

At this point, the position in the list  of `"Token 64 = Dirham"` is `8` ... not `64`.

```
        tokenList.subList(65, 77).clear();
```

If this succeeds at all, it won't have removed the element immediately after `"Token 64 = Dirham"` ...